# error from xml file in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout

when I try to run my app I get this error:

```
Process: com.a000webhostapp.mathhelperapp.www.daneshja, PID: 2789
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.a000webhostapp.mathhelperapp.www.daneshja/com.a000webhostapp.mathhelperapp.www.daneshja.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2193)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2243)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                  at com.a000webhostapp.mathhelperapp.www.daneshja.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2157)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2243) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                  at com.a000webhostapp.mathhelperapp.www.daneshja.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2157) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2243) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
               Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060063 a=-1 r=0x7f060063}
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2068)
                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
                  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3554)
                  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3484)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:464)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:236)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                  at com.a000webhostapp.mathhelperapp.www.daneshja.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2157) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2243) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is MainActivity.java:

```
package com.a000webhostapp.mathhelperapp.www.daneshja;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static int splash_time_out = 4000;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        },splash_time_out);
    }
}
```

this is my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_back">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splash_img"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/daneshja"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Start by removing `android:background="@drawable/splash_back"` and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Error inflating** class android.widget.RelativeLayout
>
> Resource **is not a** `Drawable` (color or path)

Everything looks fine except `splash_back`:

```
android:background="@drawable/splash_back">
```

There might be a problem with this file which you should remove it from code then rerun the app. If the build of new changes was successful, you better to check to see **if It is a `Drawable`** and compatible for the current background or not.